# Serializing data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

I am using mysql for adding data into the table. The problem i am facing is that the data in my table is not in Serial order like 1,2,3,4 and so on. I had to delete some entries from table due to which i got lots of gaps in table like after 2,8,25,54. These are ID as primary index for fetching data.

I have to fetch first 500 entries from the table. So for that purpose i have to serialize the data and then fetch first 500 entries.

I tried `count()` too. But it is a bit confusing while the data is not in order. So i tried looking on google and didn't found any solution.

Comment: `ORDER BY id LIMIT 500` for first 500 entries in ID order (serialized)

Comment: Also note that if you now add an entry, it goes into the gaps (to save space), so you could have 55,2,8,25,54 (55 inserted where 1 was)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LIMIT` clause to get the first 500:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
ORDER BY myPKValue
LIMIT 500
```